# How to index MongoDB Collection in Apache Nifi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

is their any way to index MongoDB collection in nifi flows. any type of scripts can we use to do indexing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.